# looking for android 12 support

Tags: android, sfdcmobilesdk-android

Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a Pending Intent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the Pending Intent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

Comment: Android 12 support is coming.

Comment: by when it will be available

Comment: Do we have a time frame on this support ?

Comment: An update including Android 12 support  will be released soon.

Answer (score 0):

MarketingCloud Mobile Push SDK v8.0.0 has been released.  This release includes support for Android 12.